# Rank of a matrix representing disjointness of the powerset of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider a $2^n \times 2^n$ binary matrix $M$, whose cells spans from $M_{0, 0}$ to $M_{2^n-1, 2^n-1}$. $M_{i, j}$ is $1$ if and only if $i \mid j = i + j$ (here $\mid$ represents the binary OR operation). That is, if you portray the indices of the cell of the matrix ($i$ and $j$) as a subset of $n$ elements, then the two sets represented by $i$ and $j$ are disjoint if and only if $M_{i, j} = 1$.

For example, when $n=2$, the matrix looks as follows:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
(note that the matrix is annotated by their row and index -- the actual matrix is the bottom-right $4 \times 4$ part).

It is implied in the book Communication Complexity (Kushilevitz et al) that the rank of this matrix $M$ is $2^n$. But I don't think this is trivial -- how do you prove this?

Comment: To be clear you are enumerating the powerset of the set with two elements?  $0 \leftrightarrow \varnothing, 1 \leftrightarrow \{0\}, 2 \leftrightarrow \{1\}, 3 \leftrightarrow \{0, 1\}$

Comment: @SammyBlack For the example, yes. For example, $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are disjoint, and that's why $M_{1, 2} = 1$.

Comment: And you believe this matrix to be *full rank* in general?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes. This is implied when the book is trying to prove that in order to cover this matrix with monochromatic rectangles (submatrices such that all their entries are the same), we need at least $2^n$ such matrices. (this follows since $\text{rank}(\sum_i M_i) \le \sum_i \text{rank}(M_i)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this by induction on $n$.  Let $P_n$ denote the power set of $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1 \}$.

Order the subsets lexicographically (having sorted the sets into descending order); e.g. for $n=3$,
$$
\varnothing \prec \{0\} \prec \{1\} \prec \{1,0\} \prec \{2\} \prec \{2,0\} \prec \{2,1\} \prec \{2,1,0\}.
$$

Notice that the first half of the sets don't contain $n-1$; hence, they form the sets $P_{n-1}$.  Furthermore, there's a one-to-one correspondence between the sets in the first half of the list $P_{n-1}$ and the sets in the second half of the list $P_n \setminus P_{n-1}$ given by
$$
X \;\longleftrightarrow\; X \cup \{n-1\}
$$

The following claim is crucial and the proof is straightforward.

**Claim:** For any $X, Y \in P_{n-1}$, 
$$
X \cap Y = \varnothing \;\Longleftrightarrow\; X \cap (Y \cup \{n-1\}) = \varnothing.
$$

The consequence of the claim is that the $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix $M_n$ indicating disjointness in $P_n$ is actually a $2 \times 2$ block matrix, with $2^{n-1} \times 2^{n-1}$ equal sized blocks, three of which are identical.
$$
M_n = \left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
M_{n-1} & M_{n-1} \\
\hline
M_{n-1} & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

By the inductive hypothesis, we can assume that the columns of $M_{n-1}$ are linearly independent (as $M_{n-1}$ has full rank).  Now, suppose that we had a linear relation among the columns of $M_n$.  Because of the zeroes in the bottom right, we would have a linear relation among the left half of the columns, but that would amount to two copies each of linear relations among the half-columns making up $M_{n-1}$.  Only the trivial relation exists by hypothesis, so may conclude that $M_n$ has full rank, too.

---

By the way, the matrix is a cropped piece of [Sierpinski's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle), which may be seen by interpreting the $(i,j)$-entry of $M_n$ as
$$
\binom{i+j}{i} \bmod{2}.
$$

Comment: Doesn't the recurrence imply that all entries under the reverse diagonal are all 0? I think this, together with the fact that the reverse diagonal are all non zero, imply that the matrix has full rank.